# Conexion remota de SQL Server linux mint 19

Tags: sql-server, linux

Tengo instalado sql server en linux mint 19, ya tengo la base de datos creada, pero, no encuentro la manera de poderla hacer accesible en la red, asi como en windows se puede acceder remotamente desde una aplicación en C# o desde SSMS.

[image: screen]

Comment: tienes habilitados los puertos respectivos para la conexion !!

Comment: por defecto sql server tiene el puerto TCP 1433...deberias habilitarlo para poder acceder a el

Comment: ya agregue los puertos al firewall abiertos para eso, es lo único que he hecho al respecto

Comment: una vez agregados...debes reiniciar el firewall para que surga efecto los cambios

Comment: podriias hacer un ping desde otra pc hacia el servidor con su puerto para ver si existe comunicacion entre ellos

Comment: ni reiniciando la maquina,  se deberá hacer alguna configuración a de mas del firewall? puede ser?

Comment: aqui tienes una guia en ubuntu: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: para habilitar el puerto uso : firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=1433/tcp --permanent

Comment: con esto reinicias el firewall: firewall-cmd --reload